# Changing numbering system of axioms

Tags: numbering

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[chapter]
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Partial Derivatives}
    \begin{theorem}[Cauchy]
        In this chapter we will discuss the matter of partial derivatives
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{axiom} The natural numbers
    \end{axiom}
\end{document}
```

The issue I'm having is that the axioms are being numbered as I.1 or I.2 instead of 1.1 and 1.2 because I have changed the numbering of system of chapters to Roman numerals in Line 2.

I'll add that I'm quite new to learning Latex, so I'm guessing there is an obvious Syntax I'm missing but I can't see to find it in the book I learning from.

My question is: How can I change it so that the axioms use Arabic numerals when referencing the chapter number? I have tried:

```
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[\Roman{chapter}]
```

But that doesn't work. What should I change to correct this?

Thanks

Comment: After defining the `axiom` environment, add `\renewcommand{\theaxiom}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{axiom}}`...

Comment: @Werner Thank you very much, that works! Can I just ask you a sort of follow-up question? Why are all these commands called \theaxiom \thechapter\thesection etc.. And how is the renewcommand function operating on the axiom environment? 
:)

Comment: Counters have an internal and an external representation. Internally, their values are represented by `\value{<counter>}`. Externally (or visually) they're represented by `\the<counter>`. Typically, with a hierarchical representation (like `axiom`s within `chapter`s), the external representation includes this hierarchy (as you've noted). One can adjust the `\the<counter>` but that won't change the actual (internal) counter representation. The `\renewcommand` just changes the counter, not the environment. The `axiom` environment is linked to the `axiom` counter by your `\newtheorem` definition.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, much appreciated for the apt explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust the representation of the `axiom` counter to

```
\renewcommand{\theaxiom}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{axiom}}
```

Here's a complete (minimal) example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\theaxiom}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{axiom}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Partial Derivatives}
\begin{axiom} The natural numbers
\end{axiom}

\end{document}
```